# Counting occurrences of a date in a list of date ranges

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I have an Excel 2010 table that lists events, giving details about the event and a beginning and ending date for each event.  These events took place over the course of a year.  I need to create a list of all the dates within that time span (done already) and get a count for each day of how many events were happening on that date.  i.e. on June 4, 2017, there were 3 events.  So my original list would appear like this:

```
Event ID  Event Name  Start Date    End Date
A12411    Event One   June 1, 2017  June 10, 2017
A45721    Event Two   June 1, 2017  June 5, 2017
A84541    Event Three June 2, 2017  June 4, 2017
```

etc...

And from the data above, I would like my list to show:

```
Date          Number of events
June 1, 2017  2
June 2, 2017  3
June 3, 2017  3
June 4, 2017  3
June 5, 2017  2
etc...
```

I've tried Countifs, both regular and array versions, with no luck (it seems to count the occurrences on the first event, but not the other...) I tried an If(and()) construction, but had even less success (lots of #Values).

I COULD conceivably write a VBA function for it, but that seems like overkill, especially since this is the first time I've encountered this and don't see it being a recurring thing.

Comment: What was your `COUNTIFS` formula that you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Given a bunch of dates in column `F` and a `ListObject` / "table" with a `From` and a `To` column containing your events' starting & ending dates, I'm getting seemingly correct results with this `COUNTIFS` formula:

```
=COUNTIFS(Table1[From],"<="&$F2,Table1[To],">="&$F2)
```

FWIW I'm getting identical results with this VBA function:

```
Public Function CountFor(ByVal calendarDate As Date, ByVal eventDates As Range) As Long
    Dim dates As Variant
    dates = eventDates.Value

    'assert eventDates consists of 2 columns
    Debug.Assert UBound(dates, 2) = 2
    Const StartDateColumn = 1
    Const EndDateColumn = 2

    Dim result As Long

    Dim eventIndex As Long
    For eventIndex = LBound(dates, 1) To UBound(dates, 1)
        If dates(eventIndex, StartDateColumn) <= calendarDate And dates(eventIndex, EndDateColumn) >= calendarDate Then result = result + 1
    Next

    CountFor = result

End Function
```

Used as follows:

```
=COUNTFOR($F2,Table1[[From]:[To]])
```

Answer (score 0):

So if your events list has start dates in column C and end dates in column D then with your date list in F2 down use this formula in G2

`=COUNTIFS(C:C,"<="&F2,D:D,">="&F2)`

copy that formula down the column and you'll have the desired count